# Recreate traceback from file

Tags: python-3.x, sentry

I have a stacktrace created by the `faulthandler` after a fatal interpreter crash. Its content looks like below:

```
File "/path/to/file.py", line <line-number> in <function-name>
File "/path/to/file.py", line <line-number> in <function-name>
```

I want to create a traceback object from this file, similar to the one from `sys.exc_info()` to upload it to sentry. Is there any module that will make it easier?

I will not have the scope variables, but it should be possible to capture the `code` object with content of the files from traceback.

For now the only solution I can think of is to create a class that will behave similar to the traceback object, but this seems like a lot of work (especially if I want the code).

Comment: Since this question is tagged with sentry I am thinking that this might be an A/B question. I wrote a blogpost about the exact question you wrote, but I am not sure if there's a good way to trim it down to a concise answer: https://unterwaditzer.net/2018/python-custom-tracebacks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have prepared my own class that behaves as a traceback object (using duck-typing). The only thing that was important to set valid `f_code.co_filename` and `f_code.co_name` and sentry client will extract the source code.